# Why is "do" sometimes put before a verb?

Tags: american-english, do-support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of “do” in affirmative statements](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24521/use-of-do-in-affirmative-statements)

Why do people sometimes use the words "do" or "does" in affirmative sentences?

For example:

> A: We know a guy!
>
> B: We do know a guy!

Why doesn't B just say: "Yes, we know a guy"?

And in general, why the use of "do" in affirmative sentences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Do* in affirmative sentences is used to put an emphasis on the positive fact.

> Person A: I've heard you don't have the piano anymore.
>   Person B: Oh, that's not true! I do have the piano!

Comment: On a tangent, what is that "do" called?  Is there a word for it?

Comment: @dr65--It's generally do-support, but I'm not sure what "do" really is.

Comment: @drm65, a modal verb?