# Why is there no form of "do" in questions of the type "who knows?"

Tags: questions, sentence-patterns, do-support

I'm wondering whether expressions like the ones below are correct or not. I've seen them several times but they don't seem to follow the typical grammatical structure.

> - Who comes? (instead of *who do come?*)
> - Who knows?
> - What happened? (instead of *what did happen?*)

So why are they constructed in this way? Are there many other expressions of this kind?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, those sentences are correct. You are wondering why these questions do not have *do* + infinitive, like most questions. I won't bore you with basic grammar lessons. The reason is that **the interrogative pronoun is the subject of the sentence**. Whenever that is the case, a question takes the same form as a statement (apart from the addition of the interrogative pronoun itself). The normal subject–verb inversion doesn't happen either, because interrogative pronouns usually need to be in first position.

> What do you do? *[you = subject]*
>
> Who knows the answer? *[who = subject]*

Note that you *could* add a form of *do* if you want to put extra emphasis on the sentence (which is normally not necessary).

> A: Did you steal her car?
>
> B: No, man! She's crazy.
>
> A: Then who *did* steal her car? She is freaking out! *[not required; emphasizes question; marks contrast with previous negative answer]*

Comment: Erm, sorry to point out, but in your last example *did* does not emphasize anything - it's a mandatory auxiliary verb. It'll be emphasizing one, if you write *But you did do something to her! She's freaking out! Tell me!*

Comment: @Philoto: Oops! You're absolutely right. I changed the question I had in mind twice, then ended up with a useless example...

Comment: I would possibly have turned the explanation round: "do" support isn't present BECAUSE there's no inversion. Saying it "doesn't happen either" makes it sound like the two observations are independent accidents.

Comment: @NeilCofey: Okay, so how does that work? Inversion entails do-support? But only in questions? What about do-support in non-questions? I wasn't sure what the relation was between the two—that's why I didn't mention it (yet).

Comment: @Cerberus: To pick up an ancient comment train, how is do-support tied to inversion? Either can occur on its own? They're far from accidents in this example, but I'm not sure how to describe their connexion here.

Answer (score 2):

It can be argued that they all follow the normal structure for intransitive verbs of subject + verb, where the subject in these cases is *who* or *what*, rather than, say, *he* or *she*.

With regard to the specific examples:

- "Who comes?" sounds a little odd. "Who is coming?" is more natural.
- "Who do come?" is incorrect, as question words like *who* take the 3rd person singular form of the verb, i.e. "Who does come?"
- "What did it happened?" is also incorrect. It should be "What did happen?"

Comment: You can use *do* in positive statement to emphasize the main verb. *I do know that* is the same as *I know that* with emphasis on the fact, that the speaker really *knows* what he is talking about.

Comment: @Philoto: That's true. However, it doesn't always sound natural, as the examples in the question demonstrate.

Comment: @Philoto: Hmm...fair point. Context is everything! Will edit answer.

Comment: They sound pretty natural to me. "What happen to your face, you're bleeding!" "Nothing, darling, it's nothing" "Don't give me this crap! What did happen to you?"

Comment: Sorry for deleting my previous comment, felt it was not good enough :)

Comment: What 1  happened?  Not: What 1  did happen? - What 1 means what is nominative. Question without to do.

Comment: @rogermue: I'm having difficulty understanding your comment. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: The problem in English is who/what can be subject case or object case.  When you ask about the subject you use who/what + verb form  (no use of do/does/did). When you ask about the object you use  who/what  and  you  form the question with do/does/did.  Romeo loved Julia. Who loved  Julia?  Who did Romeo love? -  The fire destroyed the bridge. What destroyed the bridge? What did the fire destroy? - For who/what in subject case I write who1/what1, for who/what in object case I write who4/what4.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff - Does  what I wrote help you? I know for this grammar problem there should be some exercises for learners.  But it takes some time to find the right exercises on the Internet. I found one such exercise. Can't judge whether it is optimal for you.http://www.englishexercises.org/makeagame/viewgame.asp?id=719

Comment: @rogermue:"When you ask about the subject you use who/what + verb form (no use of do/does/did)." That's true in normal usage - but it's not true if you're using "to do" as a way of emphasising what you're saying. For example, at the end of this conversation: Q: "Do you love Juliet?"; A: "No"; Q: "Then who **do** you love?". See also [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/323/303), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/24237/303), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/185713/303), [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/29450/120); + [here](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000328.htm)

Comment: And one more example is [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13469/120). I have some less-relevant comments, which I've made [over on the chat page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22183505#22183505).

Comment: Who do you love? - who is who4 (whom) and you is the subject.

Comment: @rogermue: D'oh! Just realised that. :-) Let's try again: Q:"Was it an accident?"; A:"We don't think so."; Q:"Then what **did** happen?".

Comment: Normally it would be What1 happened? Maybe some speakers put in an emphatic did: Then what DID happen? But that is not the normal thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24809/discussion-between-steve-melnikoff-and-rogermue).

Comment: So sorry, I have no experience with the chat room here. You would have to explain to me how to get there. See for yourself:http://www.eslau.ca/lesson/unit10.php

Comment: This seems to have spawned two chats; one is [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22183505#22183505), and the other is [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24809/discussion-between-steve-melnikoff-and-rogermue).

Answer (score 1):

These are shortenings of their actual expressions:

"Who comes" could either be a derivative of "Who is coming?" or "Who goes there?"

"Who knows" is a shortening of "Who could know what actually happened?"

"What happened" is another shortening of "What actually happened just then?"

They're all easier to say, that's why they were constructed like this. In speech, we tend to shorten things.

Other examples could include:

"What?" as in "What was that?"
"There" instead of "It is over there"

Comment: I can't agree. When who/what are nominative the question is formed without to do. That has nothing to do with shortenings.