# Does using "did" to form the past tense make a difference?

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

The two sentences here both indicate that, at some point in the past, I performed some work:

- I did work
- I worked

What is the difference between these two sentences? Does constructing one with *did* and the other with a simple past change the meaning?

Comment: One will be seen in most cases as ungrammatical unless the context asks for it (You didn't work - Yes, I _did_ work!), the other will by everybody be seen as correct, if used in the right context. I think you will find your question feels better at home at [English Language Learners](http://ell/stackexchange.com)

Comment: @oerkelens Actually, one is emphatic. There's probably a duplicate question...

Comment: Yup, I edited my comment. Both sentences can be used in the correct context.

Comment: There's also the case that *work* in "I did work" might be a noun, although that would really need some sort of determiner.

Comment: Indeed, this question has been asked, and answered, [16 times before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/323?sort=hot). Please search the site before asking.

Answer (score 5):

There are three common usages for the auxiliary verb *do*:

1. Emphatic *do* - strongly stressed, often contradicting something in context
   `Q`: *Why didn't you tell her?* `A`: *I **did** tell her.*
2. Active *do* - pro-verb substituting for active (non-stative) verb
   *What I want to **do** is **buy** that house now* ~ **What I want to **do** is **own** that house now*
3. [*Do*-Support *do*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78591/15299) - dummy verb, no meaning, necessary in questions, negatives, etc.

So, it depends on the construction. A simple sentence like *I did work* has to be Emphatic, because Active *do* is a pro-verb and pro-verbs only occur in certain constructions, which this is not; and *Do*-Support *do* never occurs in this construction either -- it's a marker of many constructions, but not of this one.

Auxiliary verbs are part of the syntax, and may or may not mean anything. It's the constructions they're in that are important; English syntax is about **constructions**, not words.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly grammatical indeed, but this way of sentence construction is used to emphasize that you really performed the action you are talking about. Thus

**I did work (and I did get results)**

means that you really worked (and that you really got results).

More information on emphasis you can find here:

http://www.michellehenry.fr/emphasize.htm

and here:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/ask_about_english/071112/

Answer (score 2):

### Full Answer

- I worked.
- I did work.

The word *did* in the second sentence is an example of *do*-support. This occurs because of the special role of auxiliary verbs in English. (I have changed the order of the examples for easier reading.)

### **English auxiliary verbs**

Most verb phrases in English involve at least one *AUXILIARY* verb. These verbs appear before the main verb in the sentence. There are two main types. Firstly, there are the auxiliary verbs *BE* and *HAVE*. These appear in perfect, continuous, and passive  constructions in English:

- I **have** eaten. (perfect)
- I **am** eating. (continuous)
- It **is** eaten. (passive)

Secondly, there is the family of modal auxiliary verbs. These are used to express ideas about permission, obligation, probability and so forth:

- You **may** leave.
- You **must** be polite to them.
- It **might** rain.

The nine central members of this group are: *can, could, shall, should,  may might, will, would and must*.

### NICE properties

The English auxiliary verbs have special grammatical functions, apart from the ones described above, which make them different from normal verbs. In particular, they play an important role in sentences featuring: Negation, Inversion, Code or Emphasis. (They are said, therefore, to have NICE properties).

Firstly, auxiliaries can take the adverb *not* (or contract with *-n't*) to form negative sentences. Normal verbs can't.

- He is not eating it / He hasn't eaten it/ He couldn't eat
  it.
- He ate not it/ aten't it * (wrong)

Secondly, some constructions in English require the subject and auxiliary verb to swap places. This is known as *inversion*. Normally, only auxiliary verbs can fullfil this function:

- Neither have I/Neither am I/ Neither can I.
- Neither travel I. * (wrong)
- Has she?/Is she?/Can she?
- Eats she? * (wrong)

In the following examples, the auxiliary verbs are said to be *taking code*. This means that they can appear stranded with the rest of the verb phrase omitted. The auxiliary seems to carry the meaning for the whole of the rest of the missing material. Lexical verbs can't do this:

- Have you ever been to Paris on a Friday evening with your mother-in-law?
- Yes, I **have**.  (= *been to Paris on a Friday evening with my mother-in-Law*)

Compare with:

- Do you like listening to Northern soul?
- Yes, I **like**. * (wrong)

Lastly, we can stress auxiliaries in English when we want to add affirmative emphasis to our sentences. (We can also stress them for negative emphasis, but only when contracted with the negative particle):

- Cinderella *shall* go to the ball.
- I *have* finished my homework.
- I *can* do my five times table.

### Simple tenses and *do*-support.

The present simple and past simple verb forms in English, do not standardly use auxiliaries for affirmative sentences:

- We  worked.
- I like elephants.

Here we see the main verbs *worked* and *like* occurring on their own without any auxiliaries. However, suppose we need to use Negation, Inversion, Code or Emphasis? As we've seen, only auxiliaries can enter into such constructions. If we need to do this in the present or past simple, we need to use a 'dummy' auxiliary. The dummy for these purposes is the special auxiliary *DO*. It functions as an auxiliary stand-in in present simple and past simple constructions:

- I don't eat other animals. (negation)
- I like elephants. - So do I. (inversion)
- I do. (= *take this man to be my lawful wedded husband*) (code)
- I *did* finish my homework. (emphasis).

Note that when we use *do* the main verb is an infinitive and doesn't have tense.

These occurrences of the dummy auxiliary *DO*, only occur because an auxiliary is necessary for these constructions. It does not occur in unmarked affirmative sentences. The above examples all illustrate *do*-support, in other words they show *DO* standing in as an auxiliary verb.

### The original sentences

*I worked*, then, is an unmarked, everyday, past simple sentence. There is no special reading here. The main verb carries the tense, and there is, as we would expect, no auxiliary.

The other sentence, however, is definitely marked. The presence of the dummy auxiliary is an indication that this is one of the NICE constructions. As the sentence does not involve negation, inversion, or code, the sentence is interpreted as being emphatic. There will be a sense that the affirmative truth of the sentence is being underlined. This may be occurring because there is some contrast with a negative expectation or assertion:

- You said I didn't work. I did work.
- I wasn't expecting to work, but I did work.

To sum up, although the literal meaning of the two sentences is the same, the version with do-support is marked as emphatic. The two sentences are not, therefore, interchangeable. If we used emphatic forms when we didn't need them, our English would sound very strange, and we might be misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

I did work could mean 'I performed work' with work as a noun ( e.g. I did work on the second paragraph last week but it's still not right). 
I still think that the most common use is to contradict the suggestion that you didn't work.
E.g.:
'You were supposed to do your homework, but I see you've done nothing...'
'No, I did work, but my dog got hungry...'