# Usage of do in some unusual situations

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

It surprises me when I hear someone using "do" in situations where I think it is unnecessary, as in these two examples.

> I do need help.
>
> I do have the strings.

Are these correct? Does this 'do' make any difference to the sentences I would expect to see here?

> I need help.
>
> I have the strings.

Comment: See John Lawler's answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185713/does-using-did-to-form-the-past-tense-make-a-difference/185795#185795).

Comment: Welcome. I would invite you to visit our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour), in case you are not aware of it.

Comment: The "do" just adds emphasis - either sentence is correct but the first versions have more emphasis and can be used to (at least try to) overcome a simply stated denial of the assertion (from another speaker).  Do [any of these](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/323?sort=hot) give you the answer you're looking for?