# "I did play" is it a correct sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

What is the difference between "I did play " and "I played" according to the British English?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does using "did" to form the past tense make a difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185713/does-using-did-to-form-the-past-tense-make-a-difference) or ['did shoot' vs 'shot'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323/did-shoot-vs-shot)?

Comment: They are both correct.  They have the same meansing.  Usually we use the shorter "I played".  Unless we want some special emphasis.

Comment: @GEdgar: They wouldn't usually have "the same" meaning. In any given context, one or the other is likely to be highly favoured, and using the ***less*** common alternative would normally be noticed, and assigned some significance. (Even if it's just *Speaker isn't a native Anglophone!* :)

Comment: Thank to you all for your help. So i have come to the conclusion that in the sentence "I did play " "did" is giving  emphasis on the verb"play".

Comment: *I did play* would normally be used to express the fact that you played ***habitually*** in the past. *I played* can also express that; however, if you're talking about a **single** time that you played rather than anything habitual, then *I played* would be far more commonly used. For instance, *I did play one time*, while not actually wrong, is not at all normal. But *I played one time* is very normal.

Comment: @JasonBassford thanks a lot