# Can "did" be used in affirmative sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs

> **Duplicate:**
>   [“did shoot” vs “shot”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323/did-shoot-vs-shot)
>   [When do you use “Did + 1st form” instead of “2nd form”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24237/when-do-you-use-did-1st-form-instead-of-2nd-form)
>   [Use of “do” in affirmative statements](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24521/use-of-do-in-affirmative-statements)

I know that *did* is used when asking or when using a negative sentence.

> — Did you play soccer?
>   —I didn't play soccer.

But I'm wondering whether it can be used also when we are talking about affirmative sentences.

For example, "I did play soccer" instead of "I played soccer".

It's grammatically correct?

Comment: This is your fifth question, out of five, that gets closed. I hope you are getting the message. Please search the site before asking, and please support our sister site specifically for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use 'did' to indicate you are writing in the past tense.
It can be used to add emphasis.

This question seems similar to yours:
["did shoot" vs "shot"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323/did-shoot-vs-shot?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

In *I did play soccer* which is grammatical, *did* is used for emphasis.

Comment: I don't know if it happens in real life, but courtroom dramas prefer using 'the defendant did shoot' to 'the defendant shot' etc to add gravitas. Or pompousness.