# What does "I do believe" mean?

Tags: grammar

Sentences like "I do believe" or "I do love you" are common. But I was wondering what do they mean? I've never seen structures like this in grammar.

In fact I don't understand what is the diference between these sentences and ,say ,this simple one: "I believe" or "I love you"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. *Do* is simply an intensifier; see *[“did shoot” vs “shot”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323)*. You may be interested in our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I love you = simple declaration. I really love you = passionate declaration. I *really* do love you = I want you to believe me, it's important. I *do* love you = either emphasizing or confirming this fact.

Answer (score 1):

The primary verb *do* is used in this way to emphasise the main verb.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the great many uses of *do*-support.

There are some things that in English we can't express without *do*-support, such as questions (we don't invert most verbs in standard contemporary English, so we add an inverted *do* instead; "Do you believe?") and negation ("I do not believe").

In this case, the *do* is redundant, but it's used for affirmation (if someone has questioned whether or not you believe) or for emphasis.

Comment: Thank you Jon!but One more confusion.According to you,if someone asks "Does he love me?", can one answer"Yes,he does love you"?I've never heared like this.

Comment: You certainly can, and it would be quite common as an answer. Most common would be just the plain "Yes", or "Yes, he does", but "Yes, he loves you" would also be reasonable and "Yes, he does love you" add emphasis (showing conviction of belief). It would be even more likely if the question was "Does he not love me?" since that question puts forward the negative position as a possibility, then "Yes, he does love you" uses emphasis from *do* to counter it.

Answer (score 0):

The word *do* emphasises the main verb in this context, but not necessarily in a positive way. It can bear *either* a positive *or* a negative/opposing emphasis, depending on context, or on what follows:

I *do* love you, I do *really* love you.
I *do* love you! (Darn you, how could you believe something different!)
I *do* love you, *but* I can't stay with you any longer.

I *do* believe that you didn't mean to, *but* you still broke the law.
I *do* want to believe you [actually I'm not!], *but* why did you lie to me earlier.